# How to write a function from a written statement in java

Tags: java

Below is the function that needs to be written:

PrintSolution (Cities []c): this function will print the cities in the given array c by calling the function PrintCity (c[i]) for each index i in the array

///////////////

PrintCity is another method I have written, and it's code is below

`public static void PrintCity() {     System.out.println(cityId + " " + City_X_Location + " " + City_Y_Location); }`

I tried writing a for loop but just had no idea how I would write it in this case. Basically, all the cities passed in the PrintSolution, should be printed out. The answer may be really simple but I have been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? Please provide a well-formatted [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with the current behavior of your code (including example input and output), the expected behavior of your code (also including expected input and output), and any error messages you may be encountering.

Comment: Edit your question and add the for loop you tried, and explain what problem you had.

Answer (score -2):

```
class Solution {
  static void printSolutuon(City[] cities) {
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
     printCity(cities[i]);
  }

  static void printCity(City city) {
    System.out.println(“print your city here”);
  }

  public static main(String[] args) {
    City[] cities = <array of cities here>;
    Solution.printSolution(cities);
  }
}
```